# Outlook - Rule for deleting an Email without a word

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I get at work automated emails from a "nightly build", which summarizes the build, and reports errors.

Now I am mostly interested in the case of an error, and want to ignore all other emails. So I thought to make a rule, which deletes all emails from that specific account, which don't include the word "Error" in the header of the email.

Somehow I can find only the opposite way, namely, how to delete all email that include a specified word.

Is there a way to achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a rule in Outlook, you can choose to have no conditions that will apply, meaning the rule will apply to all messages received (Outlook will even prompt you to make sure that is what you want).

[image]

After setting the action to delete, you can then apply an exception to that rule, such that it won't delete if the header contains the word "error".

[image]

Comment: I do know the sender, so I put it in. No need to "apply it to all messages". But thanks, it seems to work.